# Let $f:\mathbb{R}→\mathbb{R}$ be defined by $f(x)=\sqrt[3]{x}$. Use the definition of continuity to prove that $f$ is continuous at 0?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Let $f:\mathbb{R}→\mathbb{R}$ be defined by $f(x)=\sqrt[3]{x}$. Use the definition of continuity to prove that $f$ is continuous at $0$?

How am I supposed to do this? Can someone please help explain...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any $\epsilon > 0$ known, $|f(x) - f(0)| = |\sqrt[3]{x}-0|=\sqrt[3]{|x-0|} < \epsilon \iff |x-0| < \epsilon^3$. Take $\delta = \epsilon^3$.

Comment: Can you tell me if I got this right?

If we let $\delta = \epsilon^3$, then |$x-0$|<$\delta$ implies that $\sqrt[3]{x} < \sqrt[3]{\delta} = \epsilon$. 

So, |$x-0$|<$\delta$ implies |$f(x)-f(0)$| < $\epsilon$.

And this shows the $\epsilon-\delta$ proof holds and the function is continuous at 0?